# how to crop image based on white lines

Tags: python, image, numpy

I am trying to cut an image, in a way to remove the white lines. This image has one object in the corner, surround by blank space.
I am trying to use the following commands, but its cutting the image in a wrong way. 
 [image](http://www.image-share.com/ipng-3711-164.html)

[The first line makes the image this way](http://www.image-share.com/ipng-3711-165.html)

The second line gives an empty file.

```
image2= image[np.where((image < 255).any(axis=1))[0]]

image2[np.where((image2 < 255).all(axis=0))[1]]
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: See if this helps - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132914/crop-black-border-of-image-using-numpy

Comment: What is the shape of `image`? That is, which dimension is width, height and channels?

Comment: how can i see the channels?

Comment: I mean do you have a color image, with shape like `(width, height, 3)` or something like that?

Comment: `np.where((image < 255).any(axis=1))[0]` will return an image array by collecting any row indices with at least one pixel which isn't entirely white multiplied by the number of colour channels. Hence, the top part of the picture is cut off (nothing but white) and each row of the bottom portion of the picture (which has green pixels) is duplicated twice more, to return an image with the white portion cut off and the green portion stretched to 3x its original height.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @droooze. I understand now :)

Comment: As drooze said assuming no other white, just remove pixels with RGBA 255,255,255,255.

Comment: I don't see white lines I see two tone image. Also why up voted question is not clear or sensible way to ask to do limited possible things, possible with two tone image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you should just need to find the smallest rectangle of non-white pixels. Assuming the channel is the last dimension:

```
color_x, color_y = np.where(np.any(image < 255, axis=2))
x0 = color_x.min()
x1 = color_x.max()
y0 = color_y.min()
y1 = color_y.max()
cropped_image = image[x0:x1 + 1, y0:y1 + 1]
```

Comment: @LuizaRodrigues I've replaced it with `2` for clarity, `-1` just means "the last axis", I'm just more used to it but it is exactly the same.

Comment: The line np.where(np.any(image < 255, axis=2)) works like a charm! Thanks :)